# How to solve this error for 'Windows Azure' Conversion ASP.NET 3.5 to 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage

I found an Error when I convert my Windows Azure(ASP.NET) project .NET 3.5 to 4.0.

Getting error:
 SetConfigurationSettingPublisher needs to be called before FromConfigurationSetting can be used

Source File: 
`storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString");`

Thanks
Nahid

Comment: Googled in a second http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2011/03/05/how-to-solve-setconfigurationsettingpublisher-needs-to-be-called-before-fromconfigurationsetting-can-be-used-after-moving-to-windows-azure-sdk-1-3.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line at the beginning of your WebRole.cs and Global.asax / `Application_Start`

```
CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher((name, setter) => setter(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(name)));
```